# Multiple React components architecture

Tags: javascript, reactjs, isomorphic-javascript

I am creating a realtime dashboard which consumes an API for the data. The application is an isomorphic react app built on top of a node API, I am using the Flux architecture, more specifically the [alt implementation](https://github.com/goatslacker/alt).

My question is the dashboard has around 4/5 realtime charts (I am using [a React D3 library)](https://github.com/codesuki/react-d3-components), each chart calls an API endpoint. I have a main `<Dashboard />` component and inside this each chart component lives. My question is should the `<Dashboard />` be responsible for listening for data and passing it though as props or should each graph component be responsible for its own store/action life cycle? If I pass the data through as props this would this mean the UI would rerender more than is required?

I have yet to find any examples of React/Dashboard/Charting application so if anyone knows of any this would be very useful.

Comment: I would divide them into separate `stores`. But having it the way you mentioned should be okay. And you wouldn't rerender more than it is required. Each of your `child` components could have `componentWillReceiveProps()` and if the props didn't change you wouldn't need to rerender those components

Comment: If you pass through as props, you can catch non-changes and kill the render during `shouldComponentUpdate()` https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-shouldcomponentupdate

Answer (score 1):

It's better to keep the API access right at the top level, and just pass everything down through props. Consider putting the data from the API into a store, and using that to drive the top-level component. The practical advantages of doing it that way:

- you now have the freedom to use the same data in more than one place - it's not trapped in the child component
- testing is simplified, because you can just pass in some dummy props and confirm that you get the right result
- it's easier to reason about: the child components no longer need to care about the implementation details of where their data came from

Regarding your question about performance: Consider using [pure render mixin](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/pure-render-mixin.html) and only updating the parts of the store that need to change. That way, your chart components can very quickly tell is anything has changed, and won't re-render if nothing has changed.